# Why is it difficult to type mysql queries in Netbeans?

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, netbeans

I googled this issue so many times and could not find a correct answer. I really do not know is that only me facing this issue.

Ok here is the issue.  I am using netbeans 7.4 which supports PHP only. (I removed java plugins). I need to insert a mysql query in a php code. Lets say it is a create table command.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
forename VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
surename VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL );
```

I am used to type a new command always in a new line,(Exactly shown in the above example.  i.e create table command in one line then forename, surnames in separate lines. ) but when I try to move my cursor to a new line (or press ENTER) netbeans adds ."" at the beginning of a new line which cannot be overcome.  Why is that?. (I have given a link below to refer the screenshot of the problem. [sorry I do not have enough reputations to upload images])In addition removing one double quote from the pair is also not possible and therefore I have to type the whole mysql query in one line which I really do not like to do.
Any suggestions to avoid this problem?

URL to image
http://i1104.photobucket.com/albums/h331/dlgmu537/error_zps7e348a12.jpg

Comment: Here in SO if you want a new line in a description you have to make 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in Netbeans 7.4, this is called a new feature :).

You can disable this behaviour from the menu:

- Tools
- Options
- Edtior
- (tab) code completion
- Language, select "PHP"
- Remove the checkbox at the bottom option "Use string auto-concatenation after typed break"

This should be it.

Comment: You are correct Benz, thanks. But I would like to add some more to your steps which will help a future reader to understand your answer properly. After Navigating to code completion (4th step) I think we have to select a language from the dopdown. By default it is "All languages", but under All languages such option cannot be found. Therefore I changed it to PHP and then I could find the option you had mentioned.